# Mails from my server goes directly to spam

Tags: linux, email, postfix, plesk

I am running an ubuntu server with plesk panel, Mails sent from this server goes directly to spam folder. All records seems perfect like spf, DKIM, Domain key, PTR etc..

I'm really stuck with this. I don't know what else to check.

Mail headers are below:

```
Delivered-To: james007@gmail.com
Received: by 10.182.121.202 with SMTP id lm10csp159698obb; Mon, 14 Jul 2014 10:53:20 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.194.85.78 with SMTP id f14mr21342550wjz.36.1405360399627; Mon, 14 Jul 2014 10:53:19 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <ji@3wchat.com> Received: from xxxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxx [62.210.141.47]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id lk19si11864584wic.103.2014.07.14.10.53.19 for <james007@gmail.com> (version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128); Mon, 14 Jul 2014 10:53:19 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ji@3wchat.com designates 62.210.141.47 as permitted sender) client-ip=62.210.141.47; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of ji@3wchat.com designates 62.210.141.47 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=ji@3wchat.com; dkim=pass header.i=@3wchat.com
Received: by xxxxxxxxx (Postfix, from userid 33)    id C41CA642D61; Mon, 14 Jul 2014 19:53:19 +0200 (CEST)
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1;  q=dns; c=nofws;   s=default; d=3wchat.com;  b=lmAMOd4zaYaezuTDPVQr3eLzKh0AtsPSLhhtqtCyP95UUPwkKjXtZKxeh1u+cSAHzD04Ui7lfDpF9+H/1iTUVk5jXscie/Z9r+TUmR6+0KayPw4ub5bCmC95rt7kmC58; h=DKIM-Signature:Received:Message-ID:Date:From:To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Disposition:Content-Transfer-Encoding:User-Agent;
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=3wchat.com; s=mail;   t=1405360399; bh=c5kfmTELyaEOcYaDYPCHkLR3hrNQGoL0cmONx4TqrRo=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:From; b=Vac8uwB4b3YLvzCUyCjVNi9DVVCQlMFKOT1y2HTAUKugTlOZu25GnZVjY4pZAS+5E3XNfzAmLT9YLfxXMuA3Cx8MNFQwbp9mevIlmwe14BBxDrwOSLId1pGwQdKH0benpcooTGElJ0x7lgjwSvoHXqSKMy94q1mf54KeR7wUrt0=
Received: from 12.12.32.32([12.12.32.32]) by webmail.3wchat.com (Horde  Framework) with HTTP; Mon, 14 Jul 2014 19:53:19 +0200
Message-ID: <20140714195319.196660qgqkbu97nz@webmail.3wchat.com>
Date: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 19:53:19 +0200
From: ji@3wchat.com
To: james007@gmail.com
Subject: t
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1;  DelSp="Yes";  format="flowed"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
User-Agent: Internet Messaging Program (IMP) H3 (4.3.11) jj
```

Comment: Side note: it wouldn't hurt to mangle those email addresses. I also recommend reading [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](http://serverfault.com/q/48428/4276) from Server Fault, maybe you've missed something. And another thing: the subject ("t") is way too short it might trigger spam filters. At least that's what happened with my email server.

Comment: Antispam software should be able to tell you the reason(s) why an e-mail message has been classified as spam. Then you'll know.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, My mails are classified as spam only in google, yahoo, and hotmail. I am getting my mails straight in reddif, gmx etc..